# How come some libstdc++ iterators have operator++ but no operator+?

Tags: c++, iterator, operators, containers, std

I just noticed that for the iterator class `std::__detail::_Node_iterator` (in GCC's libstdc++, source [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.3/a00537.html)), we have an `operator++()` but no `operator+()`, so you can use `(my_set.cbegin()++)++` but you can't use `my_set.cbegin() + 2`.

Why is that? Is it just lack of syntactic sugar or is there a deeper reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard doesn't provide an `operator+` when that would be O(n), and would surprise many users.

It does provide a function [`std::advance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) you can use, if you are prepared to pay the cost.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is that? Is it just lack of syntactic sugar or is there a deeper reason?

Understanding that this might be slightly speculative on my part (I didn't design/implement iterators), my thought is that an iterator is meant to traverse a collection with some degree of *safety*. Writing something like `iterator++` will safely take you from an existing element in the collection to the next, or automatically point to `null` if you've reached the end.

It's also shorter than writing `iterator = iterator + 1` or `iterator += 1` and this might be a key reason for limiting it to `++` only. Adding all of them would seem to be redundant and unnecessary.

Quoting from the [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/) (my emphasis)

> An iterator is any object that, pointing to some element in a range of
>   elements (such as an array or a container), has the ability to iterate
>   through the elements of that range using a set of operators (**with at
>   least** the increment (`++`) and dereference (`*`) operators).

Based on this, it seems to be an intentional architectural decision to keep the client requirements for implementing iterators to a bare minimum. Note that, based on the wording above (i.e. "at least"), there seems to be no technical reason on why someone *couldn't* add support for other operators, including comparison operators other than `!=`. Whether they *should* is probably another discussion.

In addition, iterators generally traverse all objects within some range sequentially, so allowing `iterator + X` would seem to go against its intended purpose in this sense.

For example, if you do `iterator + 2`, how would you know that you're not asking for more than what the collection really has left from the iterator's current position? You could be trying to go past the end of the collection and waiting for a segmentation fault --or they would need to start throwing exceptions. The iterator's ability to *safely* traverse the collection without going out of bounds is a benefit you'd be losing here, IMHO.

An iterator is only meant to shield the clients from the implementation details of the collection. That is, a client doesn't need to know if the collection is implemented as an array, some kind of linked list, or some kind of tree. It also doesn't need to keep count of how many items the collection has, which again, makes it easier to implement and work with. (It has a single responsibility.)

Based on this, and keeping the previous 'safety' and minimalistic requirement details in mind, the decision to avoid implementing every possible operator an object could support makes sense to me.